# Web Page cannot reach reverse proxy server

Tags: javascript, html, reverse-proxy, nat

### Web page with Reverse Proxy in Local LAN only

I am trying to create an HTML page that is accessible from anywhere on my network, but can also reach my reverse proxy that allows the webpage access to a local server.

I am using Mac server, and I can access the webpage from any device from anywhere on my LAN.

My web page makes calls to an internet server successfully in this fashion:

```js
var requestURL = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/" + getFunc + "/?access_token=" + accessToken;
    $.getJSON(requestURL, function(json) {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = json.result + "%";
        document.getElementById("myRange").value = json.result;
    });
```

the server that I am using for the web page is 10.0.1.16 and is also accessible at server.local.

I tested the web app which makes calls to the server like this:

```js
  $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/data_request?id=status&output_format=json&DeviceNum=3", function(data) {
      var found = data.Device_Num_3.states.filter(function(item) {
          return item.variable === 'CurrentSetpoint';
      });
      var currentTemp = found[0].value;
      document.getElementById("mainSetpoint").innerHTML = currentTemp;
      var found = data.Device_Num_3.states.filter(function(item) {
          return item.variable === 'CurrentTemperature';
      });
      var currentTemp = found[0].value;
      document.getElementById("mainActual").innerHTML = currentTemp;
  });
```

and it works, but only when I load the webpage on the Mac server.  Any other device on the network can access the webpage, but alas it cannot access the reverse-proxy server.

where 127.0.0.1:8080 is the IP and port of the reverse-proxy.

Clearly I don't understand how this works...

Can anyone lead me in the right direction here?

**********EDIT************

I Tried setting up a reverse-proxy on my Mac server but I think I have yet another problem:

```
MacBook-Pro-5:WebPage username$ reverse-proxy -h 10.0.1.51 -p 8080 -t 10.0.1.25:3480
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 10.0.1.51:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1223:19)
    at listen (net.js:1272:10)
    at net.js:1381:9
    at nextTickCallbackWith3Args (node.js:448:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:354:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:962:3
MacBook-Pro-5:WebPage username$
```

********* EDIT 2 ****************

```
launchd     1            root    9u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c8b5b      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   10u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ceaab      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   11u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c8b5b      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   12u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ceaab      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   14u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57465b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   16u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c865b      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   20u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ce1db      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   21u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f90b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   22u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c865b      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   23u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ce1db      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   26u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c815b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   27u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd90b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   31u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c815b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   33u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd90b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   40u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a573c5b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   44u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f03b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   45u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f03b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   55u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c775b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   56u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c7c5b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   57u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd03b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   58u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cc76b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   59u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c725b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   60u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c775b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   61u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cc76b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   62u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cbe9b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   66u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a573c5b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   67u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f90b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   68u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57465b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   73u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ca42b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   74u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57375b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   75u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ca42b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   76u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57375b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   77u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57325b      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   78u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ceaaab      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   79u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ceaaab      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   80u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57325b      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   81u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51d5cb      0t0    TCP localhost:62308 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   82u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c7c5b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   87u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd03b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
kdc       103            root    6u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c635b      0t0    TCP *:88 (LISTEN)
kdc       103            root    8u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce903b      0t0    TCP *:88 (LISTEN)
awacsd    200            root    8u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57415b      0t0    TCP [fdfa:bec8:a072:c156:ca1:f89:261a:c6b2]:4488 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   11u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cbe9b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   12u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c725b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   13u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce642b      0t0    TCP *:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   14u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c595b      0t0    TCP *:631 (LISTEN)
kpasswdd  222            root    4u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c5e5b      0t0    TCP *:464 (LISTEN)
kpasswdd  222            root    6u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a520aab      0t0    TCP *:464 (LISTEN)
kadmind   223            root    4u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51e76b      0t0    TCP *:749 (LISTEN)
kadmind   223            root    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a574b5b      0t0    TCP *:749 (LISTEN)
httpd     259            root    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57285b      0t0    TCP *:8088 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   20u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a5201db      0t0    TCP localhost:53 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   21u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce6cfb      0t0    TCP server.brower.private:53 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   22u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cacfb      0t0    TCP localhost:54 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   23u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce876b      0t0    TCP 10.0.1.16:53 (LISTEN)
httpd     264 _softwareupdate    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57285b      0t0    TCP *:8088 (LISTEN)
httpd     267            root    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c4a5b      0t0    TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
httpd     267            root    7u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c6d5b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
ARDAgent  307           admin   10u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c545b      0t0    TCP *:3283 (LISTEN)
httpd     429            _www    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c4a5b      0t0    TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
httpd     429            _www    7u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c6d5b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     430            _www    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c4a5b      0t0    TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
httpd     430            _www    7u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c6d5b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
server:~ admin$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
launchd     1            root    9u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c8b5b      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   10u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ceaab      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   11u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c8b5b      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   12u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ceaab      0t0    TCP *:548 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   14u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57465b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   16u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c865b      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   20u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ce1db      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   21u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f90b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   22u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c865b      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   23u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ce1db      0t0    TCP *:625 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   26u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c815b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   27u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd90b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   40u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a573c5b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   44u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f03b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   45u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f03b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   55u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c775b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   56u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c7c5b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   57u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd03b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   58u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cc76b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   59u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c725b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   60u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c775b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   61u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cc76b      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   62u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cbe9b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   66u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a573c5b      0t0    TCP localhost:4443 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   67u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51f90b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   68u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57465b      0t0    TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   73u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ca42b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   74u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57375b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   75u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394ca42b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   76u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57375b      0t0    TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   77u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57325b      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   78u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ceaaab      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   79u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ceaaab      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   80u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57325b      0t0    TCP *:311 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   81u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51d5cb      0t0    TCP localhost:62308 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   82u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c7c5b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
launchd     1            root   87u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd03b      0t0    TCP *:1640 (LISTEN)
kdc       103            root    6u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c635b      0t0    TCP *:88 (LISTEN)
kdc       103            root    8u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce903b      0t0    TCP *:88 (LISTEN)
awacsd    200            root    8u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57415b      0t0    TCP [fdfa:bec8:a072:c156:ca1:f89:261a:c6b2]:4488 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   11u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cbe9b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   12u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c725b      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   13u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce642b      0t0    TCP *:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd     216            root   14u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c595b      0t0    TCP *:631 (LISTEN)
kpasswdd  222            root    4u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c5e5b      0t0    TCP *:464 (LISTEN)
kpasswdd  222            root    6u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a520aab      0t0    TCP *:464 (LISTEN)
kadmind   223            root    4u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a51e76b      0t0    TCP *:749 (LISTEN)
kadmind   223            root    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a574b5b      0t0    TCP *:749 (LISTEN)
httpd     259            root    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57285b      0t0    TCP *:8088 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   20u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3a5201db      0t0    TCP localhost:53 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   21u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce6cfb      0t0    TCP server.brower.private:53 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   22u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cacfb      0t0    TCP localhost:54 (LISTEN)
named     261            root   23u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f39ce876b      0t0    TCP 10.0.1.16:53 (LISTEN)
httpd     264 _softwareupdate    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f3a57285b      0t0    TCP *:8088 (LISTEN)
httpd     267            root    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c4a5b      0t0    TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
httpd     267            root    7u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c6d5b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
ARDAgent  307           admin   10u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c545b      0t0    TCP *:3283 (LISTEN)
httpd     429            _www    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c4a5b      0t0    TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
httpd     429            _www    7u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c6d5b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     430            _www    5u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c4a5b      0t0    TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
httpd     430            _www    7u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c6d5b      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
screensha 976            root  fp.u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd90b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN) (fileport=0x1b03)
screensha 976            root  fp.u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c815b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN) (fileport=0x1c03)
screensha 976            root    4u  IPv6 0xd1f0298f394c815b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
screensha 976            root    5u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f394cd90b      0t0    TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
node      985           admin   12u  IPv4 0xd1f0298f3bea21db      0t0    TCP localhost:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because 127.0.0.1 is your loopback address on your reverse-proxy server. And using that address only works from the machine in question.

Try using the LAN IP of the reverse-proxy server (probably 10.0.1.x).
I guess the reverse-proxy server runs on the Mac server.

Comment: I did try that and got errors setting it up...   I'll edit my original post

Comment: I know nothing about Macs but the error could be because the port is already being used by another server. What does `netstat -nap |grep 8080` return?

Comment: As I said, I don't know how to work a Mac but this should probably be run as root. If it doesn't work then the netstat command doesn't exist or has different parameters than on Linux I guess.

Comment: I edited my post with the output from :server:~ admin$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"

Comment: You already have a node process listening on port 8080, see last line of your dump

Comment: That did it.  Last night in the middle of the night I understood what you meant and tried it and it voila!  I still have an issue, but I will start a new post... thanks!